# Syntax for CentOS Environment Config File

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, systemd

I am trying to modify the file /etc/sysconfig/httpd on CentOS 7.

This file modifies the environment for the httpd service under systemd.

I want to modify the PATH variable by adding to it. I can set it, but I am struggling with the right syntax to add to it.

If I use this:

```
PATH="/export/home/www/perl5/bin:$PATH"
```

..then what I get in PATH on Apache is actually:

```
/export/home/www/perl5/bin:$PATH
```

In other words, it is not interpolating the $PATH variable.

I have tried a bunch of different syntaxes, but I haven't got it to work yet.

Does anybody know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

[systemd does not support variable expansion when setting Environment=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=). The workaround is to just spell out the full set of paths you need to set.

Otherwise, the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` you pasted looks like it has good advice on the transition to Apache being managed by `systemd`

Answer (score 0):

```
man /etc/sysconfig/httpd

#  # This file is no longer used to configure additional environ‐
ment variables # for the httpd process.  # # It has been replaced
by systemd. If you want to customize, the best # way is to create
a file "/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service", # containing #   .in‐
clude  /lib/systemd/system/httpd.service #   ...make your changes
here...   #  For  more  info  about  custom  unit  files,  see  #
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_custom‐
ize_a_unit_file.2F_add_a_custom_unit_file.3F


# To set OPTIONS environment variable which was set in this  file
# in older versions, you need to create a file named # "/etc/sys‐
temd/system/httpd.service" containing: #       .include /lib/sys‐
temd/system/httpd.service  #       [Service]  #       # #       #
To pass additional options (for instance, ‐D definitions) to  the
#       #  httpd  binary at startup, set OPTIONS here.  #       #
#       Environment=OPTIONS=‐DMY_DEFINE

# Note: With previous versions of httpd, the MPM could be changed
by # editing an "HTTPD" variable here.  With the current version,
that # variable is now ignored.  The MPM is  a  loadable  module,
and  the # choice of MPM can be changed by editing the configura‐
tion file # /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00‐mpm.conf.  #
```

This is from fedora 23, but I'm sure it's similar enough to give you pointers, else run "man /etc/systemd/httpd" yourself on your machine.

Comment: This is just the contents of the file. I'm not seeing the specification of the correct syntax to do what I want to do here. If I'm missing it, I might need it spelled out to me a bit more. Same on my own machine: just the contents of the file.